# db2 UPDATING TWO TABLES IN 1 QUERY

Tags: db2

Is it possible to update 2 tables in 1 query? I'm using db2 and this is what im trying to do.

UPDATE Table1, table2 SET column = 'Y' WHERE REFERENCENUMBER = xxxxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating two table in one query is not possible.
You must do like.

UPDATE Table1, SET column = 'Y' WHERE REFERENCENUMBER = xxxxxx
UPDATE Table2, SET column = 'Y' WHERE REFERENCENUMBER = xxxxxx

Comment: ahhh ok thanks, so i really have to do 2 separate update queries.